# Android: Menu.xml error : No Resource matches the given name

Tags: android, xml, menu

i am trying to make a simple menu for my android application. But don't know why i am getting the following error in my menu.xml file:

```
[2012-07-21 11:53:27 - Torchit] W/ResourceType( 5469): Bad XML block: header size 46936 or total size 163847776 is larger than data size 0
[2012-07-21 11:53:27 - Torchit] /home/tigerstyle/workspace/Torchit/res/menu/menu.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/menu_item_about').
```

The menu.xml code is as follows:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@id/menu_item_about"
      android:title="About"
      android:icon="@drawable/menu_about" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a "+" after the "@" like this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_about"
      android:title="About"
      android:icon="@drawable/menu_about" />
</menu>
```

Without that, it looks for a resource which has already been defined with that id.